# Search an multi array and return index

Tags: arrays, powershell

I have this array:

```
$Cluster = @( ("vcdvc012", "CL-CC5-DR"),
    ("vcdvc013", "CL-CCL3-DR"))
```

Now I would like to search for "vcdvc012" to be able to get as result "CL-CC5-DR".

What is the best way to do this? 
Gabrie

Comment: The best way is to replace it with a hashtable or an array of objects with multiple properties so you don't need multi-level array in the first place

Comment: I would like to re-enforce @FrodeF.'s comment, since while the answers below do provide an answer, there is probably a better way to do what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$Cluster | ? { $_[0] -eq 'vcdvc012' } | % { $_[1] }
```

Answer (score 0):

Frode has a general answer but it relies on knowing the location of the element. Since you are dealing with arrays the operators `-contains` and `-in` would be beneficial here. Won't change much for the selection of the second element unless you created your own custom objects.

```
$Cluster | Where-Object {$_ -contains 'vcdvc012'} | ForEach-Object{ $_[1] }
$Cluster | Where-Object {'vcdvc012' -in $_} | ForEach-Object{ $_[1] }
```

Both would work just the same. The latter is more intuitive as many confused the functionality of `-contains`. `-in` was made available in v3.0